# A problem occurred configuring root project"my hope"

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this error  everytime i'm trying to create a new project in android studio.
can you tell me what's the solution for it?

A problem occurred configuring root project 'myhope'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0-release-764.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
> Required by:
> project :

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

[build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60FQb.png)

Comment: Not enough information. Can you post your build.gradle files

Comment: I've added a screen capture to the question .thanks.

Comment: It's fixed in Android Studio 4.2.1: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/05/android-studio-421-available.html

Comment: thanks .it's all good for now.